# How to disable creating literals without lit?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

While working with Spark (Scala) it sometimes happens to me that I accidentally forget a `$`. Minimal example:

Given some data:

```
val foo = Seq((1, "Chicago"), (2, "Berlin")).toDF("b", "city")
val bar = Seq((1, "USA"), (2, "Germany")).toDF("a", "country")
```

I write the following:

```
foo.join(bar, $"a" === "b").show
```

which behaves equivalently to:

```
foo.join(bar, $"a" === lit("b")).show
```

But what I actually wanted to write is:

```
foo.join(bar, $"a" === $"b").show
```

Is there a way to prevent the language / type system / Spark Shell from accepting my expression that uses neither `$` not `lit`?

Comment: nice to see others made the same mistakes, I've wasted hours in the last yours because of this typo :)

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Thank you. So I'm not the only one. :) Yesterday it took me almost an hour to find this kind of error in a script.

Comment: you can use this syntax to avoid issue with $:   foo.join(bar, foo("b") === bar("a")).show

Comment: @RamdevSharma A bit more verbose, but not bad! Thanks. Edit: Meh, it gets weird on longer join chains without names for the intermediate dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `===` on `Column` accepts `Any` (taken for source-code):

```
 def === (other: Any): Column = withExpr {
    val right = lit(other).expr
    if (this.expr == right) {
      logWarning(
        s"Constructing trivially true equals predicate, '${this.expr} = $right'. " +
          "Perhaps you need to use aliases.")
    }
    EqualTo(expr, right)
  }
```

So there is no magical implicit convertion her...

What you could to is the use the Pimp-My-Library pattern, unfortunately you cannot override the existing `===` (AFAIK), but you could implement `====` which will only compile for  `Columns`

```
implicit class MyColumn(c:Column) {
  def ==== (other: Column): Column = {
    c===(other)
  }
}
```

Then, `foo.join(bar, $"a" ==== "b").show` will not compile

Comment: Perfect! I'll use this. Thanks. :)